# Laravel relationship between 3 models (group,member,post)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have 3 models that are related to each other.

1. Group
2. GroupMember
3. GroupPost
4. GroupPostComment

Now, I have separeted the database tables aswell.

1. groups
2. group_members
3. group_posts
4. group_post_comments

For each group a member is a member of, I insert a new row in group_members.
The foreign key here is "group_id", wich relates to the id field in groups.
In group_posts there is a new row for every post posted. This container a group_id field aswell.

What I'm struggling with is the GroupMember model.
How can I get an collection of all the posts from this GroupMember, that the GroupMember posted in that one group its related to?

Here is my models setup.

**Group model**

```
public function category() {
    return $this -> belongsTo('App\GroupCategory', 'category_id');
}

public function owner() {
    return $this -> hasOne('App\GroupMember', 'group_id') -> where('owner', true);
}

public function mods() {
    return $this -> hasMany('App\GroupMember', 'group_id') -> where('mod', true);
}

public function admins() {
    return $this -> hasMany('App\GroupMember', 'group_id') -> where('admin', true);
}

public function members() {
    return $this -> hasMany('App\GroupMember', 'group_id');
}

public function posts() {
    return $this -> hasMany('App\GroupPost', 'group_id');
}

public function comments() {
    return $this -> hasMany('App\GroupPostComment', 'group_id');
}
```

**GroupMember model**

```
public function group() {
    return $this -> belongsTo('App\Group');
}

public function posts() {
    return $this -> hasMany('App\GroupPost', 'group_id', 'group_id');
}

public function comments() {
    return $this -> hasMany('App\GroupPostComment', 'group_id', 'group_id');
}

public function user() {
    return $this -> belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**GroupPost model**

```
public function user() {
    return $this -> belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function comments() {
    return $this -> hasMany('App\GroupPostComment', 'post_id');
}

public function group() {
    return $this -> belongsTo('App\Group');
}
```

The problem is the GroupMember model and the posts() / comments() method.
There is an error in my relation, but I can't see what I am doing wrong.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case is a little bit confusing to resolve, although easy to. I guess that's why you haven't received any help yet because some people struggle to understand.

**1. Clear some confusions**

In your title you mentioned

> Laravel relationship between 3 models (group,member,post)

Yet, there is no `Member` model to be seen. And I think most of your difficulties come from there. In my tryout, I will assume you have a `User` model and the table that goes with.

Question: Can a user be member of many groups ? If the answer is yest, then you have a many to many relationship between `Group` and `User` (members). Thus, update your `Group` model like this:

```
public function members() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'group_members', 'group_id', 'member_id');
}
```

And in the `User` model, you define the opposite

```
public function groups() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group', 'group_members', 'member_id', 'group_id');
}
```

Right, you noticed now `group_members` table has a composite key made of `group_id` and `member_id` respectively representing `groups` and `users` table.

**2. How to get the all the posts belonging to a member in a specific group**

First thing first, a `GroupPost` (post) belongs to two entities: a `Group` and `User` (member). In your GroupPost model you already have a relationship to User. So all good. To answer your questions, there are many possibilities.

```
//Direct eloquent when user id and group id are known
$posts = GroupPost::where('user_id', 1)->where('group_id', 1)->get();

//Directly from the user 
$member = User::find(1);
$posts = $member->groupPosts()->where('group_id', 1)->get();
```

Don't forget to define `groupPosts()` relationship in `User` model

```
public function groupPosts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\GroupPost');
}
```

Comment: There is a member model: "GroupMember" and yes, a "User" can be a "GroupMember" of many "Groups". There is a new "GroupMember" for each "Group" the "User" is a member of. I'm not sure I quite understand what you meant by that there are no member model to be seen, but I'll try some of the things you have mentioned in the answer and see if they'll work. Thank you.